# JsonMappingException - Cannot map valid object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jackson

I need to map newly created object using `jackson.map.ObjectMapper` in @Test method:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TestProductServiceController implements ApplicationContextAware  {
    @Autowired
    private ProductService cService;
    @Autowired
    private ProductPropertyService crService;
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    String json;
    ProductProperty productProperty;
    Product product;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(new ProductServiceController());
        cService = (ProductService) context.getBean("productService");
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddProduct() throws IOException {
        productProperty = crService.findProductProperty(1);
        product = new Product();
        product.setProduct(1); 
        product.setDateTimeStart(...);
        product.setDateTimeEnd(...);
        product.setFk_product_property(productProperty);
        product.setName("Test 1");
        product.setCancelled("F");
        Hibernate.initialize(product);
        Hibernate.initialize(product.getMapped_product_part_collection());
        Hibernate.initialize(productProperty);
        Hibernate.initialize(productProperty.getMapped_fk_product_property());
        String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(product);
        }
private static ApplicationContext context;

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    context = applicationContext;
}

public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
    return context;
}
     }
```

**Error:**

```
 JsonMappingException  failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: model.ProductProperty.mapped_fk_product_property,
         could not initialize proxy - no Session
         (through reference chain: model.Product["fk_product_property"]->model.ProductProperty["mapped_fk_product_property"])
```

---

```
@Table(name = "product")
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "product")
  private int product;

@ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_product_property", referencedColumnName = "product_property", nullable = false)
  private ProductProperty fk_product_property;
  }
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_property")
public class ProductProperty implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "product_property")
  private int product_property;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fk_product_property", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
      private Collection<Product> mapped_fk_product_property;
      }
```

---

I think it is not correct to apply `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` to `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "fk_product_property", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
          private Collection<Product> mapped_fk_product_property;`. What's wrong? What is the solution for current `@TEST` method?

**UPDATE**

I added to  @TEST but getting error:

```
Hibernate.initialize(product);
Hibernate.initialize(product.getMapped_product_part_collection());
Hibernate.initialize(productProperty.getMapped_fk_product_property()); //    HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have following structure in debugger at `Hibernate.initialize(productProperty.getMapped_fk_product_property());`:

```
-product={...}
  -name=...
  -....
  -fk_product_property = {....}
     -name=...
     -....
     -mapped_fk_product_property={org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag@2222} unable to evaluate expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception.
```

Comment: no need to make it `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`, instead try using `Hibernate.intialize(product);Hibernate.intialize(product.getmapped_fk_product_property());` just before `String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(product);`

Comment: It gives `org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session`

Comment: so you ar enot even saving `product`, post the complete code please

Comment: post complete code from your test program file

Comment: try returning fully intialized object from `crService.findProductProperty(1);` itself. Intialize `productProperty.getMapped_fk_product_property()` in service itself.

Comment: `crService.findProductProperty(1);` gets all fields correctly except `mapped_fk_product_property()` which has : `Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception.`

Comment: `productProperty.getMapped_fk_product_property()` cannot be initialized because it's located in DAO, not service.

Comment: wherever it is located try intializing it first before wrapping to json

Comment: Error is apparently at `-mapped_fk_product_property` which is `@OneToMany` and not parent of the relation (parent is `Product`). I have run out of ideas how to initialize / resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between `ProductProperty` and `Product` is `OneToMany` and the owner of the association is `Product`, so when you try to fetch the `ProductProperty` elements the `Product` will not get loaded if the fetching strategy is not `EAGER`

Now in this line of code:

```
productProperty = crService.findProductProperty(1);
```

you are trying to get `ProductProperty` elements from your service class `crService`. It means the fetching logic is present in DAO layer where you are having the Hibernate's `Session`
Also the collection elements `mapped_fk_product_property` will be set to proxy object as the fetching strategy is `LAZY` in this case.

Now in this line of code:

```
Hibernate.initialize(productProperty.getMapped_fk_product_property());
```

you are tryig to initialize the collection elements using `Hibernate.initialize(Object)`, the problem with this line of code is you are trying to call initialize after the session was closed in DAO layer itself. So the exception says :

```
could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

To fix this issue, add this line of code in DAO layer where you are trying to fetch the `ProductProperty`:

```
Hibernate.initialize(productProperty.getMapped_fk_product_property());
```

Also as per Java coding guidelines it is not recommened to have underscores "_" for variable declaration, so try to avoid them in your code.

Comment: I found workaround: in  `ProductPropertyDAO` I set `setMapped_fk_product_property(null)` there is no other way to fetch as i understand. I see no reason to fetch those because there is already existing relation and this is just a child (parent is `Product`). Is it correct? If no provide code example because `Hibernate.initialize(....)` seems like not helping.

Comment: @RCola, updated my answer with clear explanation. You are calling initialize at wrong place, it should be called only where you have session opened not outside once it is closed.